# What functionality should go into Zend Framework modules?

Tags: zend-framework, hmvc, zend-framework-modules

I'm a bit puzzled about Zend Framework modules.
I mean - I understand that you would usually want to have  frontend and backend module... right?

But - What else would you separate out into modules?

can someone who uses Zend Framework professionally give an example of what modules they have in their application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Zend MVC lingo a module is an independent part of your application. For example if you want to write a Content Management System you will probably have different modules like

- Main application (user login, application bootstrap etc.)
- Blog
- News
- Admin panel
- Image gallery

Basically each of these modules could act as a separate application (although they will eventually be interconnected). The module approach also gives you an easy way for permission management (e.g. users can only pay for using certain modules).

Comment: hmm. So - If I would like to have admin section from where I handle different aspects of blog module for example or news module - like removing blogentries or adding news etc, - would I just create for example blog/news etc. controllers under admin module? Wouldn't that defeat a purpose o separating those into different modules.

Comment: I have a similar problem in separation in a current project, but basically, you could also add an admin controller into each module. I created an admin module, because I know, that an administrator will have access to every other module of the application as well. Creating new blog posts stays in the blog module, but higher level settings like giving a user permission to add blog posts goes in the admin module.

Answer (score 2):

As addition to Daffs answers we could try to figure out some guidelines for deciding between choosing a 'controller' or a 'module' to implement a certain bundle of functionality.

### When to use a 'controller':

- when there is a considerable degree of dependency on different models of the same module
- when there is a considerable degree of interaction with other controllers of the same module
- when the functionality can be covered with a few methods/actions
- when the functionality is clearly just a bundle of subordinated functionality of the given module
- when the functionality can be easily maintained together with the rest of the code (versioning, deployment, ...)

### When to use a 'module':

- when there are no or almost no dependencies with the main modules controllers and models
- when the bundle of functionality can be seen as a separate (sub)application
- when the functionality can't be covered with a few methods/actions and thus has to be broken down into several controllers
- when versioning and deployment needs independence from main module